# 2 queries - 1 SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: t-sql

I have the following T-SQL job that I run - I need to pull invoices and credit notes into the one email - however, in two separate tables:

```
DECLARE @bodyMsg nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @subject nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @tableHTML nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @tableHTML2 nvarchar(max)

SET @subject = 'Invoices & Credits in Past Week'

SET @tableHTML = 
N'<style type="text/css">
#box-table
{
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: center;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-top: 7px solid #9baff1;
border-bottom: 7px solid #9baff1;
border-spacing: 10px;
}
#box-table th
{
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: normal;
background: #b9c9fe;
border-right: 2px solid #9baff1;
border-left: 2px solid #9baff1;
border-bottom: 2px solid #9baff1;
color: #039;
border-spacing: 10px;
padding: 15px;
}
#box-table td
{
border-right: 1px solid #aabcfe;
border-left: 1px solid #aabcfe;
border-bottom: 1px solid #aabcfe;
color: #669;
border-spacing: 10px;
padding: 15px;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color:#eee; }
tr:nth-child(even) { background-color:#fff; } 
</style>'+ 
N'<H3><font color="Red">Invoices from Past week</H3>' +
N'<table id="box-table" >' +
N'<tr>
<th>Invoice #</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Account #</th>
<th>Customer</th>
<th>ex GST</th>
</tr>' +
CAST ( ( 

SELECT
td = OINV.DocNum ,'',
td =CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), OINV.DocDate, 3) ,'',
td = OINV.CardCode ,'',
td = OINV.CardName ,'',
td = '$' + CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(money, OINV.DocTotal-OINV.VatSum-OINV.TotalExpns), 1) 
FROM OINV INNER JOIN OSLP ON OINV.SlpCode = OSLP.SlpCode 
WHERE OSLP.SlpName = 'SALES REP' and OINV.DocDate > DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) )

@tableHTML2 = 
N'<style type="text/css">
#box-table
{
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: center;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-top: 7px solid #9baff1;
border-bottom: 7px solid #9baff1;
border-spacing: 10px;
}
#box-table th
{
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: normal;
background: #b9c9fe;
border-right: 2px solid #9baff1;
border-left: 2px solid #9baff1;
border-bottom: 2px solid #9baff1;
color: #039;
border-spacing: 10px;
padding: 15px;
}
#box-table td
{
border-right: 1px solid #aabcfe;
border-left: 1px solid #aabcfe;
border-bottom: 1px solid #aabcfe;
color: #669;
border-spacing: 10px;
padding: 15px;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color:#eee; }
tr:nth-child(even) { background-color:#fff; } 
</style>'+ 
N'<H3><font color="Red">Credits from Past week</H3>' +
N'<table id="box-table" >' +
N'<tr>
<th>Credit #</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Account #</th>
<th>Customer</th>
<th>ex GST</th>
</tr>' +
CAST ( ( 

SELECT
td = ORIN.DocNum ,'',
td =CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ORIN.DocDate, 3) ,'',
td = ORIN.CardCode ,'',
td = ORIN.CardName ,'',
td = '$' + CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(money, ORIN.DocTotal-ORIN.VatSum-ORIN.TotalExpns), 1) 
FROM ORIN INNER JOIN OSLP ON ORIN.SlpCode = OSLP.SlpCode 
WHERE OSLP.SlpName = 'SALES REP' and ORIN.DocDate > DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
N'</table>' 

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients='email@email.com',
@profile_name = 'SQL Alerts',
@subject = @subject,
@body = @tableHTML,
@body = @tableHTML2,
@body_format = 'HTML' ;
```

This T-SQL script runs when I only have @tableHTML in the query.

I need to find out why the above is erroring?
Any help appreciated!

Regards
Rick

Comment: `@tableHTML` is just a string variable. You can add more to it like this: `SET @tableHTML = @tableHTML + '<H1>A Heading</H1>'`. Do you have a query for your AR Credit Memos?

Comment: yes - i was just going to copy the above SELECT statement, but change all references from OINV to ORIN.

I have tried to copy everything from SET tableHTML = through to N'</table>', then added it after N'</table>'  - I altered the tableHTML to tableHTML2. Then I've added a new declare statement at the top for tableHTML2 - but this doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Almost thereL: after you populate `@tableHTML2`, put this line: `SET @tableHTML = @tableHTML + '<BR><BR>' + @tableHTML2`, and remove the `@body = @tableHTML2,` from your subsequent call (so you only have one `@body = @tableHTML,`). I do suggest that you wrap all of this up in a stored procedure and just call the stored procedure from the job.

Comment: You also need to change `@tableHTML2 = ` to `SET @tableHTML2 = `. I also suggest you move all formatting out to an external CSS too.. but just get this working first. If you do... post your result as an answer. If this is for a particular ERP you might want to tag that too